# Remote PC can't print to a virtual PDF printer unless we connect to it via TeamViewer

Tags: windows

User can't print to a virtual PDF printer unless I connect to their PC using TeamViewer. Has anyone ever experienced this before and know of a solution. Very weird!

Randy

Comment: Randy - I've seen similar issues with printers due to a conflict in the RDP redirected printers or drivers and correlated issues.... For a potentially simple solution, simple **UN**check the **`Printers`** option from the **`Local Resource`**  tab... See this screen print: https://i.imgur.com/aAHR2fv.png. Let me know if this helps and I'll add as an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) rather than a comment.